# Blender 2.80: Different collections in each viewport

Tags: python, interface, add-on

Is it possible to restrict visible collections in each viewport separately.

Here is how it was done in 2.79 using lock_camera_and_layers
[image: 2.79 lock_camera_and_layers]

Comment: Blender 2.80 is still in Beta. As of now, this feature is not implemented. See [developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/T61327) for further information.